# Is it possible to use autotest with a Perl project?

Tags: perl

I am currently working on a Mojolicious app using TDD on my Mac and I am getting a bit fed up of having to manually run my tests every time I change some code.

After doing some Rails development, I really started to like the automatic response I got from the autotest gem, and as wondering it there is a Perl equivalent or if there is some way to use autotest with Perl.

Comment: What constitutes "manually running your tests"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility is the [Test:: Continuous](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::Continuous) suite. It includes the autoprove command, which reruns the test suite after source file updates:

```
% sudo cpan Test::Continuous
% cd MyModule/
% autoprove
```

Answer (score -2):

The [Test](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/Test.html) module is your friend.

Take a look at [Test::Simple](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/Test/Simple.html) too, or go take a look at all of the various Test modules at http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/index-modules-T.html. If they're listed here, they're all part of the standard Perl distribution. In fact, if you write CPAN modules, you have to write a test suite using these Test modules to go with it.

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking how to write tests, but how to make them run automatically when code changes.  Also, don't use Test.pm any more.  It's interface is confusing, it's unmaintained and it doesn't play nice with other Test modules.

Comment: @Schwern, can you elaborate on Test.pm?  What is a good replacement module for testing?

Comment: @Kevin Test::Simple and Test::More are the replacements.